# Browser upgrade warning message

Tags: browser, cross-browser

As the sole developer at my company, I'm really tired of supporting older browsers (mostly IE). I'd like to display a nice message to the user that lets them know they're using a deprecated browser, that things may not work quite right and instructions on how to upgrade. Is there a hosted JS widget I might be able to include in the page that would accomplish this?

I'm not against making my own, just thought it may be nice to use an existing service if such a thing exists.

(Out of roughly 10k uniques a month, 5% use IE 7 or below.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you might want to try something like this: http://browser-update.org/